# Median Algorithm in O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, median

How can we remove the median of a set with time complexity O(log n)? Some idea?

Comment: What representation is being used to store this set in the computer?

Comment: is the set ordered?  in that case it's constant

Comment: I think he's asking for a data structure that provides a median removal operation with O(log n) time complexity.

Comment: Is it stored on a balanced tree? that makes a huge difference.

Comment: I want to do a 'structure' that can find the median in O(log n) and remove other elements in O(log n)....Did you understand?

Comment: @Franzé Jr.: that's exactly what I posted in my answer.  With an underlying data structure providing removal in O(log n), e.g. a self-balancing binary search tree, you can keep track of the median and provide it in O(1) and remove elements in O(log n) time.

Answer (score 18):

If the set is sorted, finding the median requires O(1) item retrievals.  If the items are in arbitrary sequence, it will not be possible to identify the median with certainty without examining the majority of the items.  If one has examined most, but not all, of the items, that will allow one to guarantee that the median will be within some range [if the list contains duplicates, the upper and lower bounds may match], but examining the majority of the items in a list implies O(n) item retrievals.

If one has the information in a collection which is not fully ordered, but where certain ordering relationships are known, then the time required may require anywhere between O(1) and O(n) item retrievals, depending upon the nature of the known ordering relation.

Comment: depending on how it's being stored, one could keep track of the median as items are inserted.

Comment: @aaronasterling But the insertions themselves are not free; they're at best O(1), and there are n of them... so that adds a factor of O(n).

Comment: @Tylle McHenry  While what you say is certainly true, it may be that the cost is easier to bear at insertion time than at removal time.

Comment: @aaronsterling -- That doesn't change the fact that the algorithm is necessarily O(n).  It doesn't matter if you pay the price at insertion time or at removal time-- one way or another, you have to touch every item.

Comment: @MichaelDorfman: Depending upon the distribution of the data, there may be cases where one can avoid touching absolutely every item.  For example, if the first 502 items in an unsorted list of 1,000 items are 500 sixes, a two, and a nine, the median is six.  I don't think any such scenarios will allow a precise median calculation less than O(n), however.  Still, there may be some probalistic approaches which could, in sub O(n) time, be expected to yield a value that was close to the median, especially if something is known about the distribution of input items.

Comment: @MichaelDorfman: I would expect that such techniques are probably used pretty routinely by practical statisticians, though I'm not sure whether there's anything interesting algorithmically about them (simply finding the median of 100 items chosen at random from a list would yield O(1) performance and usually give something close to the precise answer, but isn't very interesting; more interesting might be an adaptive approach which estimated the number of items required to give a good estimate, but that would seem to depend on the expected input distribution).

Comment: Nico's solution demonstrates that O(n) minimum is true if we assume the set is stored as an array, but an alternative data structure can allow an O(logn) median finding time.

Comment: @sbwoodside: If there is no known ordering relationship among data items, finding the median will require time O(n).  Finding the median of data stored in a red-black tree is faster *because of the known ordering relationship among the data therein*.  To be sure, a set may have an ordering relationship which can help with finding the median even if it's not "fully" sorted, but for data with no known ordering relationship my point stands.

Answer (score 5):

For unsorted lists, repeatedly do [**O(n)** partial sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) until the element located at the median position is known. This is at least **O(n)**, though.

Is there any information about the elements being sorted?

Comment: Partial sort is O(kn), where k is the rank of the desired element. In case of the median element we want k = n/2. So this algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: I should probably remove my answer. (It has been more than a decade since I posted it.) My point is that, provided that the list of N elements have never been "treated" (parsed, sorted, converted into a data structure), the time is at least N (every element has to be visited at least once), so the question looking for a O(log N) cannot have an answer, until the question has been edited to clarify the assumptions (especially on the choice of data structure or pre-treatment.) The question could also be clarified by asking specifically about what data structures should be used, etc. (cont'd)

Comment: There is also the question of "time from data ingestion (N items) to first query (and item removal)" and "time to subsequent queries (and item removals)". For example, if the choice of data ingestion is to fully sort them and put them on a flat array (time O(N log N) best and average; space O(N); median-of-medians pivoting can help avoid worst case, merge sort can guarantee best time at the expense of double space requirement), time to subsequent operations is always O(1).

Answer (score 4):

For a general, unsorted set, it is impossible to reliably find the median in better than O(n) time. You can find the median of a sorted set in O(1), or you can trivially sort the set yourself in O(n log n) time and then find the median in O(1), giving an O(n logn n) algorithm. Or, finally, there are more clever median selection algorithms that can work by partitioning instead of sorting and yield O(n) performance.

But if the set has no special properties and you are not allowed any pre-processing step, you will never get below O(n) by the simple fact that you will need to examine all of the elements at least once to ensure that your median is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution in Java, based on TreeSet:

```
public class SetWithMedian {
    private SortedSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    private Integer m = null;

    public boolean contains(int e) {
        return s.contains(e);
    }
    public Integer getMedian() {
        return m;
    }
    public void add(int e) {
        s.add(e);
        updateMedian();
    }
    public void remove(int e) {
        s.remove(e);
        updateMedian();
    }
    private void updateMedian() {
        if (s.size() == 0) {
            m = null;
        } else if (s.size() == 1) {
            m = s.first();
        } else {
            SortedSet<Integer> h = s.headSet(m);
            SortedSet<Integer> t = s.tailSet(m + 1);
            int x = 1 - s.size() % 2;
            if (h.size() < t.size() + x)
                m = t.first();
            else if (h.size() > t.size() + x)
                m = h.last();
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the median (i.e. "s.remove(s.getMedian())") takes O(log n) time.

**Edit**: To help understand the code, here's the invariant condition of the class attributes:

```
private boolean isGood() {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return m == null;
    } else {
        return s.contains(m) && s.headSet(m).size() + s.size() % 2 == s.tailSet(m).size();
    }
}
```

In human-readable form:

- If the set "s" is empty, then "m" must be
  null.
- If the set "s" is not empty, then it must
  contain "m".
- Let x be the number of elements
  strictly less than "m", and let y be
  the number of elements greater than
  or equal "m".  Then, if the total
  number of elements is even, x must be
  equal to y; otherwise, x+1 must be
  equal to y.

Answer (score 4):

Try a [**Red-black-tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). It should work quiet good and with a binary search you get ur log(n). It has aswell a remove and insert time of log(n) and rebalancing is done in log(n) aswell.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it shows that other answerers have assumed that the set is stored in a simple array.

Comment: Are we assuming that the O(n*log(n)) complexity of actually creating the set is not being considered?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in previous answers, there is no way to find the median without touching every element of the data structure. If the algorithm you look for must be executed sequentially, then the best you can do is O(n). The deterministic selection algorithm (median-of-medians) or BFPRT algorithm will solve the problem with a worst case of O(n). You can find more about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm

However, the median of medians algorithm can be made to run faster than O(n) making it parallel. Due to it's divide and conquer nature, the algorithm can be "easily" made parallel. For instance, when dividing the input array in elements of 5, you could potentially launch a thread for each sub-array, sort it and find the median within that thread. When this step finished the threads are joined and the algorithm is run again with the newly formed array of medians.

Note that such design  would only be beneficial in really large data sets. The additional overhead that spawning threads has and merging them makes it unfeasible for smaller sets. This has a bit of insight: http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/research/EXPAR/papers/3494/node18.html

Note that you can find asymptotically faster algorithms out there, however they are not practical enough for daily use. Your best bet is the already mentioned sequential median-of-medians algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I know one randomize algorithm with time complexity of O(n) in expectation.

Here is the algorithm:

Input:  array of n numbers A[1...n] [without loss of generality we can assume n is even]

Output: n/2th element in the sorted array.

Algorithm ( A[1..n] , k = n/2):

Pick a pivot - p universally at random from 1...n

Divided array into 2 parts:

L - having element <= A[p]

R - having element > A[p]

if(n/2 == |L|) A[|L| + 1] is the median stop

if( n/2 < |L|) re-curse on (L, k)

else re-curse on (R, k - (|L| + 1)

Complexity:
 O( n)
 proof is all mathematical. One page long. If you are interested ping me.

Comment: No, this is O(n), dividing array into L and R takes linear time.

Answer (score 2):

Master Yoda's randomized algorithm has, of course, a minimum complexity of n like any other, an expected complexity of n (*not log n*) and a maximum complexity of n squared like Quicksort. It's still very good.

In practice, the "random" pivot choice might sometimes be a fixed location (without involving a RNG) because the initial array elements are known to be random enough (e.g. a random permutation of distinct values, or independent and identically distributed) or deduced from an approximate or exactly known distribution of input values.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on rwong's answer:  Here is an example code

```
// partial_sort example
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main () {
  int myints[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+9);
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  partial_sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+5, myvector.end());

  // print out content:
  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:
myvector contains: 1 2 3 4 5 9 8 7 6

The element in the middle would be the median.